# How to "initialize" Material 3 theme design in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, implementation, material3

I'm sure this is a newbie question, but I'm trying to implement a Material 3 theme.  I have added the themes.kt & colors.kt to my com.my.project.ui.theme package.  But I don't understand what I can do next to implement these colors as my app is not using these colors and is still using the default material 3 colors that came when I started the app.  I'm not finding the disconnect.

I have added the dependencies and removed the old Material dependency

```
    //implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.3.1'

    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:1.1.0-alpha03"
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-flowlayout:0.24.8-beta"
```

One thing I notice is the function in themes.kt is saying it is never used (grayed out).

```
@Composable
fun DzoicTheme(darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(), content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    val useDynamicColors = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S
    val colors = when {
        useDynamicColors && darkTheme -> dynamicDarkColorScheme(LocalContext.current)
        useDynamicColors && !darkTheme -> dynamicLightColorScheme(LocalContext.current)
        darkTheme -> DarkColors
        else -> LightColors
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colors,
        typography = Typography,
        shapes = Shapes,
        content = content
    )
}
```

Where does this function get called (DzoicTheme)? Default was AppTheme but instructions said to change it.  Is the name important here?  Most tutorials show utilizing material 3 colors from the activity compose functions but I do all my design in xml layout files, does this matter?  Any help here would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your main activity:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            DzoicTheme {
                // your main composable
            }
        }
    }
}
```